# The bug stops here

Tags: code-golf

Let's discover<sup>1</sup> some bugs...

Write the shortest complete program possible that, when run on a **stable** release of an implementation of a language, demonstrates a bug in that implementation. Please specify which release and platform was used. This is code golf, so the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

- An implementation bug is any behavior that contradicts the language's official standard or specification.
- This does not include bugs in the language's standard library.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid submission (measured in **bytes**) wins.

<sup>1 OK, you don't actually have to find the bug. But if you do, don't forget to file a bug report! :)</sup>

Comment: Would a memory leak be considered a bug?

Comment: That would b a bug in the program, not the compiler. So no, that does not count.

Comment: @Quincunx well, it would count if you can get the compiler to leak memory when it shouldn't, or to get it to unexpectedly cause your program to leak.

Comment: Using this definition of a bug, any C program with undefined behavior has no bugs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Golfscript, 4

```
2-1?
```

This produces output of `1/2` in the interpreter downloaded from [golfscript.com](http://www.golfscript.com/) and `0.5`on [web golfscript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/). There aren't supposed to be floats in golfscript, but the latest compiler has this on line 82: `Gint.new(@val**b.val)` and it seems to miss a cast to int.

Comment: Hmm, this one will probably be quite hard to beat. I foresee a green check mark in this this answer's future... ;)

Comment: Technically, it's a Rational with the standard interpreter, but GolfScript isn't supposes to have those either...

Answer (score 3):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 256 bytes

```
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 1 l 2 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:w 1 l.Go to Go More:n 2 l.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY6xDsIwDER/5Ta2SmXsihATCIkvsEoULExcnEQtXx9Kw4LEAItt@U53L9HEpbTgiJE4cfCghFMi6y8sZxzyzZmK@kfzk2mnSPpV6ka0EKxhy663NEfur3kAYaAYXfDO4PXVMMds75lkFbFRC87@sVaMz2cFeEvz3Ku5LiwQpTwB)

I'm not 100% sure this counts but, based on the [map of Townsburg](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/map-big.png), `Go More` is the 2nd left when heading north from `Equal's Corner`. However, the little dead-end road that is the 1st left (the one that `Starchild Numerology` is on) doesn't have any nodes on it. Thus, as far as the [official interpreter](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/taxi.cpp) is concerned, it's not a road. Thus, `Go More` is actually the *first* left. If you run the above program, you'll get:

```
error: cannot drive in that direction
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) (GHC 8.0.2 on TIO), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to @Angs</sup>

```
f::()
f=w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P83KSkOTK822/P9/AA)

I have no idea what's happening here. A constant with a type signature defined to be a nonexistent identifier causes an ICE ("impossible happened") on TIO Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 11 bytes

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.47(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$
$ $[2**63%-1]


Warning: Program '/bin/bash' crashed.
```

Comment: Just as quick as using the `exit` command...

Comment: Where did you get that warning message from? It would be better to include the original error (*Floating point exception*) instead.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: That's what my terminal emulator (Konsole) shows.

Comment: @Dennis I guess that's because you tried it directly in the terminal instead of starting another bash instance manually first.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: I did. I like it better that way. Hit enter, watch blinking red cursor, shell is gone.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 7 bytes

```
$ xxd bug.sh
0000000: 2431 3c3c 5f0a 01                        $1<<_..
$ bash bug.sh xxd 2>&-
0000000: 0a                                       .
$ dash bug.sh xxd 2>&-
0000000: 01                                       .
```

Comment: I actually did find this on my own, although I assume it's well-known. Drove me crazy for about an hour until I finally figured out why my Bash script wasn't working...

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 4 bytes

```
?1;?
```

This should be equivalent to:

```
PRINT 1;
PRINT
```

Printing the number `1` without a trailing linebreak, then moving to the next line.

However, it throws the error `Type mismatch(PRINT:3)` after printing `1`.

The bug is that PRINT only has 2 arguments, while the error refers to a third argument which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 5.5, 31 bytes

```
(new GlobIterator("*"))->key();
```

When it is executed in an empty directory, it throws:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'The parent constructor was not called: the object is in an invalid state ' in Command line code on line 1

It shouldn't throw any exception. It doesn't throw any exception if the glob pattern (`*`) matches at least one file in the directory.

It is also present in PHP 5.3 and 5.4. PHP 5.3 cannot parse the code above, it requires the object created by `new` to be stored in a variable before running any of its methods (35 chars after stripping the unneeded white space characters):

```
$x = new GlobIterator("*");
$x->key();
```

It is bug [#55701](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55701) and it [has been fixed](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1880) in July 2016 for PHP 5.6 and 7.0. It was also present in these versions until it was fixed. The versions released after the fix (7.1 and 7.2) don't have this bug.

It was not fixed for PHP 5.5 and older versions because they were already beyond their support phase at that time.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 5 or 6, 12+ bytes

```java
enum M{M;{/* Code here */}}
```

In Java versions 1 through 7, all<sub>1</sub> Java programs should have an endpoint class containing a main-method:

```java
class M{public static void main(String[]a){/* Code here */}}
```

And in Java 8 through 10 you should have this as well, or optionally an interface instead:

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){/* Code here */}}
```

In Java versions prior to Java 7, it was due to a bug possible to use a static block instead like this: `class M{static{/* Code here */}}`, to run code without a main method. It will still give the following error to STDERR, but only after it has executed the code inside the static block:

> M
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
> Exception in thread "main"

In Java 5 and 6 this could also be done without static block in an `enum`, as displayed at the top of this answer, which is also mentioned on the [*Tips for Golfing in Java* page by *@OlivierGrégoire*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140181/52210). Also mentioned on that tip page is that you can get rid of the error to STDERR by changing it to:

```java
enum M{M;{/* Code here */System.exit(0);}}
```

This might be useful if a challenge states it isn't allowed to error and requires a full program (although in the current meta functions are allowed, and [errors to STDERR after you've already completed the challenge are also allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/52210)).

<sub>*1. Note that [`java.applet.Applet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) or [`javafx.application.Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) classes can run independent without a main-method, although their general use is to be embedded inside another application.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## J, 24 Bytes

```
(".@,quote)'(".@,quote)'
```

This works on all versions I've tried.

Infinite recursion should throw a stack error, for example, in `$: 0`. However, the `".` verb (eval) seems to fly under the radar, and this crashes the interpreter with a segmentation fault.

Based on the quine

```
(,quote)'(,quote)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/X0NJz0GnsDS/JFVTHZn9/z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## C++ (gcc 4 or 5) + Boost, 94 bytes

I'm not sure exactly which versions of gcc this will or won't work on. The guy who [originally reported the bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81321) says the bug is present in gcc4 and gcc5, so I will take his word on it. Personally, I tested it with 5.4.0

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <cstdarg>
int a(const boost::any&x){}int b(va_list l){a(l);}
```

Attempting to compile this produces:

```
$ gcc gccbug.cpp 
gccbug.cpp:3:50: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 int a(const boost::any&x){}int b(va_list l){a(l);}
                                                  ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```